# Как правильно организовать классы в desktop-приложении на основе swing

Tags: java, swing

Не могу понять, как организовать классы в desktop-приложении на основе `swing`. В частности, я не понимаю, как разграничить код, описывающий логику приложения и код описывающий gui. Например, если я пишу калькулятор, как мне отделить код математических функций от кода интерфейса? Во всех учебниках, что я видел, все смешивается в одну кучу. Вот, например, [типичный образец](https://ru.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE) . В нем код, реализующий подсчёт ворон в том же классе, что и код gui. 
Если же мне все таки удаётся это разграничить (весьма не тривиально, в силу моей неопытности), встает вопрос, как, например, передать 2 числа, которые ввёл пользователь в TextField, в функцию, которая их сложит, и которая находится в другом классе (в классе с другими мат.функциями). Не хочу вдаваться в частности и приводить пример кода, думаю, суть вопроса ясна.
Не могу сформулировать вопрос, что бы самостоятельно решить проблему с помощью гугла. Что почитать /поискать, что бы внести ясность организацию классов в приложениях, типа калькулятор? (я знаком с парадигмой ооп, нужно больше конкретики) 
Заранее благодарен. Прошу прощение за возможную глупость вопроса, это мое будет мое первое приложение.

Answer (score 0):

**Swing** использует паттерн **MVC**. Вам так же нужно использовать похожий паттерн.

Ваш калькулятор, то что производит математические вычисления, это **модель**. Ваш **графический интерфейс**, то что взаимодействует с пользователем, это **представление (view)** и **контроллер**.

Когда пользователь нажимает кнопку, то кнопка передает это событие **контроллеру**, а тот в свою очередь изменяет **модель**. **Модель** оповещает **представление (view)** об изменениях и **представление** их отображает.

Вот очень простая реализация паттерна **MVC** [SimpleMVC](https://github.com/Vaysman/SimpleMVC).

Answer (score 0):

http://myflex.org/books/java4kids/JavaKid8x11_ru.pdf
**Глава 5 ДЕЛАЕМ ГРАФИЧЕСКИЙ КАЛЬКУЛЯТОР** (стр.76)